# How to compare the time for two days for a particular scenario in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

My shcema as follows:

order.js:

```
order_time: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
```

and restaurent.js:

```
 restaurent_starting_timing_one: { type: String, required: true },
 restaurent_closing_timing_one: { type: String, required: true },
```

Here what I want is :

when `restaurent_closing_timing_one` has values like `0:30 or 7:30 or 4:15 etc`, it should show the order for two days, otherwise for one day.

So is there anyway I can achieve this ?

Comment: It would be a pleasure for me to answer you but I don't understand what you want

Comment: say with some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getOrders = (restaurent => {
    const selectedTime = ["0:30", "0:30", "4:15"];
    const days = selectedTime.includes(restaurent.restaurent_closing_timing_one) ? 2 : 1;

    const currentTime = moment();

    const startTime = currentTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    const endTime = currentTime.subtract(days, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");

    orders.find({
        order_time: {
            $gte: new Date(endTime),
            $lt: new Date(startTime),
        }
    })
});
```

I haven't tested it but this should work. You might need to modify few things as per your usecase